# Mass Update NoSQL Documents: Bad Practice?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm storing two collections in a MongoDB database:

==Websites==

`id
nickname
url`

==Checks==

`id
website_id
status`

I want to display a list of check statuses with the appropriate website nickname.

For example:

[Google, 200] << (basically a join in SQL-world)

I have thousands of checks and only a few websites.

Which is more efficient?

1. Store the nickname of the website within the "check" directly. This means if the nickname is ever changed, I'll have to perform a mass update of thousands of documents.
2. Return a multidimensional array where the site ID is the key and the nickname is the value. This is to be used when iterating through the list of checks.

I've read that #1 isn't too bad (in the NoSQL) world and may, in fact, be preferred? True?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only a few websites I'd go with option 1 - not as clean and normalized as in the relational/SQL world but it works and much less painful than trying to emulate joins with MongoDB. The thing to remember with MongoDB or any other NoSQL database is that you are generally making some kind of trade off - nothing is for free. I personally really value the schema-less document oriented data design and for the applications I use it for I readily make the trade-offs (like no joins and transactions).

That said, this is a trade-off - so one thing to always be asking yourself in this situation is why am I using MongoDB or some other NoSQL database? Yes, it's trendy and "hot", but I'd make certain that what you are doing makes sense for a NoSQL approach. If you are spending a lot of time working around the lack of joins and foreign keys, no transactions and other things you're used to in the SQL world I'd think seriously about whether this is the best fit for your problem.

Comment: It'll be potentially thousands of websites, but millions of checks. Initially, I picked a NoSQL database for the ease of replication/cluster-like setup. It seemed like a better option than trying to handle replication/sharding with SQL - no?

Comment: So do you need the nickname? That appears to be the only truly unique item in the Websites collection. You could just use URL for most cases and only look up the nickname as needed.

Comment: Yea, I think that's what I'm going to do. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You might consider a 3rd option: Get rid of the `Checks` collection and embed the checks for each website as an array in each `Websites` document.

This way you avoid any JOINs and you avoid inconsistencies, because it is impossible for a `Check` to exist without the `Website` it belongs to.

This, however, is only recommended when the `checks` array for each document stays relatively constant over time and doesn't grow constantly. Rapidly growing documents should be avoided in MongoDB, because everytime a document doubles its size, it is moved to a different location in the physical file it is stored in, which slows down write-operations. Also, MongoDB has a 16MB limit per document. This limit exists mostly to discourage growing documents.

You haven't said what a `Check` actually is in your application. When it is a list of tasks you perform periodically and only make occasional changes to, there would be nothing wrong with embedding. But when you collect the historical results of all checks you ever did, I would rather recommend to put each result(set?) in an own document to avoid document growth.

Comment: The checks grow at an enormous rate -- a new entry per minute per day. I thought about doing this initially, but I heard constant appends are to be avoided. If I split up the collections into `Checks` and `Websites`, it makes sense to keep the `nickname` out of checks -- why should a `check` care about the `nickname` of the `website`? It sounds like I should avoid trying to fake a JOIN and also having constant appends to a document. Perhaps I'll settle without displaying the `nickname` and only show the `URL`. Thoughts?